# Is it important to have Hessian positive definite for trust region method optimization?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

We can do local approximation with quadratic functions (with Hessian matrix). Is it important to have Hessian positive definite at the point? If quadratic approximation is not convex, does that hurt any in way?

Comment: Important for what?

Comment: I am thinking "trust region method for optimization", but do not how to phrase it correctly.

Comment: Related question ["Second derivative test for machine learning algorithms"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344212/second-derivative-test-for-machine-learning-algorithms).

Comment: "trust region method for optimization" phrasing is fine.

Comment: so basically, when the hessian is positive definite, the geometric of the probability distribution over that point is convex, which means there is a local or global minima